# flicker is coming before and after playing a video clip

Tags: android

I am playing a video when I click on a button. But at that time a flicker (black flash) is coming before and after that video clip. Any suggestions. Thanks in advance

Below is my code

```
babyFace=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.babyFace);
    lEye =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.lEye); 
lEye.setOnClickListener(DisplayListener);
private OnClickListener DisplayListener=new OnClickListener (){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View image) {

                    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.babypalyface/raw/mdpi_l_dimple");
                    playVideo();
                    }

private void playVideo()
    {

        videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
                videoView.setOnCompletionListener(VideoViewListener);
  }
OnCompletionListener VideoViewListener=new OnCompletionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            videoView.destroyDrawingCache();
            videoView.clearFocus();
            videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
    };
```

Comment: Hi Pinky, can you post code of playing video

Comment: @ Sunil Kumar Sahoo: see i am providing my code

Comment: I have the same problem... eventhough the videoView only uses 50% of the UI, the whole screen flickers black when the video starts to play. After the video is started the whole screen is (and video is playing properly). VERY ANNOYING !!

Answer (score 0):

Modify below code to play your video. Suggest you .. before showing the content to user give some time to download few bytes of content. Hope this helps

```
public class PlayVideo extends Activity{
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    int increment;
    VideoView video;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        video = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView01);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        video.setMediaController(mc);
        video.setVideoPath("rtsp://v5.cache8.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQnAHrGa4Moc0RMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBWluZGV4YO7F8s7Fh92ZTAw=/0/0/0/video.3gp");
        increment = 1;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        // set the progress to be horizontal
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        // reset the bar to the default value of 0
        dialog.setProgress(0);

        int maximum = 100;
        // set the maximum value
        dialog.setMax(maximum);
        // display the progressbar
        dialog.show();
        // create a thread for updating the progress bar
        Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    Thread.sleep(20000);
                    progressHandler
                            .sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());

                } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
                    // if something fails do something smart
                }
                Looper.loop();
            }
        });

        // start the background thread
        background.start();




    }
      // handler for the background updating
    Handler progressHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            dialog.incrementProgressBy(increment);
            dialog.dismiss();
            video.start();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: i need to play video on click on image video .its a small video of 4 sec only no need of progress bar i need to show immediately

Comment: ok gr8 don't show progress bar... just invoke  seprate thread to download video and start video inside handleMessage.

Comment: my video file is in raw folder

Comment: Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.sample.package/"+R.raw.vidd); Now for Videoview use videoview.setVideoUri(uri).. Video should play now